# let user input image destination through console OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tried several ways to implement a way to let user input the file destination of a imagefile, so it can be loaded in a `Mat`. I cant figure out how to do it. I am learning OpenCV through their guides, but i cant find any information about how to load an image through console.

This is the code i have so far, but its not working..

```
Mat src
string path;
cout << "Load nyt billede" << endl<<"Fildist(Hele filstien): ";

cin >> path;
src=imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

imwrite("test", src);
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >>` will stop parsing at spaces, use `std::getline()` instead:

```
std::getline(std::cin, path);
```